# Undefined offset: 90 in /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2_twp/vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/ResourceModel/ReadHandler.php on line 168 in magento 2?

Tags: magento2

I am migrating my website from **Magento 1.7** to **Magento 2**. In my backend , whenever i am trying to edit any product URL redirection , I am getting `Undefined offset: 90 in /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2_twp/vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/ResourceModel/ReadHandler.php on line 168`